# Prove that $\left|\left|I-\frac{ss^t}{s^ts}\right|\right|=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $0\neq s\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $$\left|\left|I-\frac{ss^t}{s^ts}\right|\right|=1$$

I truly don't have idea on how to solve this. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$M=I-\frac 1{s^t s} ss^t$$

The matrix being symmetric, let's look at its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

First, let $u\in\mathbb R^n$ be a vector orthogonal to $s$. Then $s^t u=0$, and $$Mu=u$$
So $u$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $1$. The space of vectors orthogonal to $s$ being of dimension $n-1$, we know that $1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n-1$. We now need to find the last eigenvalue of $M$.
Now note that $$Ms=s-s=0$$ so $M$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue.

To summarize, $M$ has two eigenvalues: $1$ (multiplicity $n-1$) and $0$ (multiplicity 1).

It follows that $$\|M\|=1$$

Comment: Here is just to warn you that there is the stupid case $n=1$, where $M=0$, so $\Vert M\Vert =0$.  The OP unfortunately never said $n>1$ (although one can easily guess).

Comment: Why the norm is $1$ at the end? Which relation did you use?

Comment: See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9302/582769

Answer (score 0):

This is a less elegant, more 'analysis' approach.
For any $v\in\mathbb R^n$, we have

$$ss^tv = s \cdot \langle s, v\rangle,$$

so $ss^tv$ is a multiple of $s$.
On the other hand, $s^ts = \langle s,s\rangle = \lVert s \rVert^2$.
Hence, for $v \in\mathbb R^n$ we have

$$\left(I - \frac{ss^t}{s^ts} \right)v = v - \frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\, s,$$

and thus

\begin{align}
\left\lVert \left(I - \frac{ss^t}{s^ts}\right)v \right\Vert^2
&=
\left\langle
v - \frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\, s
, v - \frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\, s
\right\rangle
\\&=
\langle v, v \rangle
- 2 \left\langle v, \frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\,s\right\rangle
+\left\langle
\frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\, s
, \frac{\langle s, v\rangle}{\lVert s \rVert^2}\, s
\right\rangle
\\&=
\langle v, v \rangle - \frac{2\,{\langle v, s\rangle}^2}{\lVert s \rVert^2}
+\frac{{\langle v, s\rangle}^2}{\lVert s \rVert^2}
\\&=
\langle v, v \rangle - \frac{\,{\langle v, s\rangle}^2}{\lVert s \rVert^2}.
\end{align}

Now, if $\lVert v \rVert = 1$, we have

$$\left\lVert \left(I - \frac{ss^t}{s^ts}\right)v \right\Vert^2
=
1 - \frac{\,{\langle v, s\rangle}^2}{\lVert s \rVert^2}$$

so that $\left\lVert I - \frac{ss^t}{s^ts} \right\Vert \leqslant 1$.
To see that $1$ is achieved, it suffices to take $v$ with $\langle v, s\rangle = 0$, that is, any $v$ orthogonal to $s$.

Comment: what's the difference between dot product and inner product here?

Comment: The dot product is the usual inner product for euclidean space (which induces the L2 norm).